I am a beginner to python. How can I make my program loop to the beginning using a while loop?
This is my code:
import random

Player_1 = input ("Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors")

computer_choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
computer_move = random.choice(computer_choices)
print(f"Computer chose: {computer_move}")

if Player_1 == computer_move:
    print("Both players chose the same thing. The game is a draw!")

elif Player_1 == "Rock":
    if computer_move == "Scissors":
        print("Player with Rock wins!")
    else:
        print("Player with Paper wins!")
    
elif Player_1 == "Paper":
    if computer_move == "Rock":
        print("Player with paper wins!")
    else:
        print("Player with Scissors wins!")
    
elif Player_1 == "Scissors":
    if computer_move == "Paper":
        print("Player with scissors wins!")
    else:
        print("Player with Rock wins!")
    
play_again = "yes"
while play_again.lower() == "yes":
    play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (yes/no): ") 

the issue specifically is that after I say "yes" it just asks again and doesnt loop to the beginning of the program. It just asks if want to play again. How can I get it to loop?
I tried changing some of the code around like maybe putting it all within a while loop but I do not think it works that way.

"maybe putting it all within a while loop but I do not think it works that way." - yes, it works that way.

The usual solution is to put all of your code inside a while loop, like this:
while True:
    # all the code for playing
    # the game goes here

    answer = input("Do you want to play again?")
    if answer == "no":
        break


Wow it was really that simple. Thank you this was perfect. The other replies also show another way to do it. Its great that there are so many different ways to do the same thing. Thanks for the help.

All this will do is loop this one operation:
while play_again.lower() == "yes":
    play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (yes/no): ")

Because that one operation is all that's inside the loop.  If you want to repeat the entire game in a loop then the entire game would go in the loop.  For example:
import random

play_again = "yes"
while play_again.lower() == "yes":
    Player_1 = input ("Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors")

    computer_choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    computer_move = random.choice(computer_choices)
    print(f"Computer chose: {computer_move}")

    if Player_1 == computer_move:
        print("Both players chose the same thing. The game is a draw!")

    elif Player_1 == "Rock":
        if computer_move == "Scissors":
            print("Player with Rock wins!")
        else:
            print("Player with Paper wins!")
    
    elif Player_1 == "Paper":
        if computer_move == "Rock":
            print("Player with paper wins!")
        else:
            print("Player with Scissors wins!")
    
    elif Player_1 == "Scissors":
        if computer_move == "Paper":
            print("Player with scissors wins!")
        else:
            print("Player with Rock wins!")
    
    play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (yes/no): ") 

Notice in this case that all of the code being repeated is inside the loop.

Currently, when your code gets to:
play_again = "yes"
while play_again.lower() == "yes":
    play_again = input("Do you want to play again? (yes/no): ") 

Its just going to ask for the users input regarding the string "Do you want to play again? (yes/no)", and then the program ends.
Your program has no instruction to go back or loop back to the beginning of the program.
You need to either fit entire code within a while loop or place current code within a function and call the function again if it meets certain parameters.
I am posting another example in order to give you more options and show you that there are a few ways to skin this cat.
import random

import sys

def rps():
    Player_1 = input ("Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors \n")
    computer_choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    computer_move = random.choice(computer_choices)

    if Player_1 == computer_move:
        print("Both players chose the same thing. The game is a draw!")

    elif Player_1 == "Rock":
        if computer_move == "Scissors":
            print("Player with Rock wins!")
        else:
            print("Player with Paper wins!")
    
    elif Player_1 == "Paper":
        if computer_move == "Rock":
            print("Player with paper wins!")
        else:
            print("Player with Scissors wins!")
    
    elif Player_1 == "Scissors":
        if computer_move == "Paper":
            print("Player with scissors wins!")
        else:
            print("Player with Rock wins!")
    else:
        sys.exit()
    
    wanna_play_again()
    

def wanna_play_again():
    play_again = input("Do you want to play again? yes/no Rock\n")
    play_again = play_again.lower()
    if play_again == "yes":
        rps()
    else:
        sys.exit()

rps()

I hope this helps you in your python learning journey.

Don't use recursion in place of looping.

@Barmer, you are indeed correct as recursion uses more memory and processing resources. Thanks for the correction.

Plus there's a limit to recursive depth. And in your case it's halved because each recursive step is 2 levels.
